# How to remove the last git commit in Ubuntu 20.40

Tags: git

I have pushed a git commit mistakenly that I want to remove. I've tried this command `git reset --hard HEAD^` but it throws a fatal error. Something like `fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD^': unknown revision or path not in the working tree. Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this: 'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you already pushed the commit, you will need to revert it. Resetting will only modify your local repository.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I revert a Git repository to a previous commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-do-i-revert-a-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the output from `git reset`, the commit you're trying to remove is the *first, last, and only* commit.  This is what is causing the problem.

It's always technically impossible to *remove* any commit, but normally we can get Git to stop *seeing* the last commit in a chain of commits, using the `git reset` command you're trying to use.  The reason for this is simple enough, but requires a bit of background knowledge about Git.

A Git repository is, at its heart, a big collection (or database) of *commits*.  Nothing else really matters: it's really the *commits* that matter.  You may have branches and tags, but the point of these branches and tags is to help you (and Git) *find* commits, and the reason you want them is that the "true name" of a commit is some big ugly random-looking hash ID number, such as <sub><sup>`cefe983a320c03d7843ac78e73bd513a27806845`</sup></sub>.  This isn't something anyone is going to remember, but a simple *name* like `master` or `main` will make *Git* remember the number for you.

Now, each commit has one of these numbers, and that one number is unique to *that* commit.  It's not merely unique in *your* Git repository.  It's unique in *every Git repository in the universe*.  That number means *that* commit, never any other commit.  So two Git repositories, meeting in the dead of night (or a sunny day) over some internet connection, can tell which commits each other has, and hence one can obtain only those commits that are *new to it*.  The two Gits have the *same commit* if they both have one with the *same number*.

That's what a lot of this is about: the numbers let your Git talk to another Git, and the two will immediately—or at least very quickly—know who has what, and hence a `git fetch` or `git push` can package up something pretty small and deliver that.

But, given this feature of commits, there's another trick your Git software will use with your repository.  Namely, each commit:

- stores a full snapshot of every file, as of the form that file had at the time you (or whoever) made the commit; and
- stores some *metadata*, or information *about the commit itself:* who made it, when, and so on.

In the metadata for any one given commit, Git stores the raw hash ID of the *previous* commit (or sometimes commits, plural: these are *merge commits*).  What this means is that commits link to earlier commits.  **The commits form a chain.**  This chain works *backwards*, so Git itself works backwards too.

Given some chain of commits, we can draw a picture of that chain.  Let's use single uppercase letters like `H` (for Hash) to stand in for real commit hash IDs, because the real hash IDs are too big and ugly for us.  Then if `H` is the *latest* commit, `H` has, stored inside it, the hash ID of some earlier commit.  Let's call that commit `G`.  We'll say that commit `H` *points to* earlier commit `G`:

```
          G <-H
```

But commit `G` has, stored inside *its* metadata, the hash ID of some still-earlier commit `F`.  So we haven't drawn the above quite right.  Let's fix that:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

Commit `F`, of course, points to some still-earlier commit, which points backwards yet again, and so on.

In order to *find* a commit, Git *needs the hash ID*.  So somehow, we have to give Git the actual hash ID for the latest commit `H`, if we want to use that latest commit `H`.

What we do is have *Git* store that hash ID for us, in a *branch name*.  We then say that the *branch name* points to the commit, and when we draw that in, we end up with:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <-- main
```

That is, the *name* `main`, which is easy for us humans to remember, holds the hash ID of the *latest commit* `H`.  So that lets us—and Git—find `H` easily.  Then, commit `H` points backwards to earlier commit `G`, which lets Git find it easily.  (We might have to run `git log` and let Git show us the hash IDs, for instance, to find it ourselves, but Git can find it easily.)  Commit `G` lets Git find `F` easily, and so on: so Git *works backwards*, just as we said earlier.

When we use `git reset` the way you are—with `git reset --hard HEAD^`—what we're doing is telling Git: *First, find the latest commit `H`* (that's the `HEAD` part here) *and then step back once to an earlier commit `G`* (that's the `^` suffix).  *Then make the branch name point to that commit.*  So if we start with:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- main (HEAD)
```

—I've gotten a bit lazy about drawing in the internal arrows—and we run this kind of `reset` command, we end up with:

```
          H
         /
...--F--G   <-- main (HEAD)
```

Commit `H` *is still in the repository*.  We don't actually *remove* it: we can't do that directly.  Git will eventually clean it out, on Git's own timetable, whatever that may be.<sup>1</sup>  But because *we* find the *latest* commit using the *name*, and the name now finds commit `G` instead of commit `H`, we'll *think* that commit `H` is gone: we won't *see it any more* when we use the branch name.

This works great for a while: we can keep re-setting commits away:

```
           E--F--G--H
          /
A--B--C--D   <-- main (HEAD)
```

eventually becomes:

```
  B--C--D--E--F--G--H
 /
A   <-- main (HEAD)
```

Or, if we only actually *have* one commit to start with, we start with:

```
A   <-- main (HEAD)
```

Note that `A` *doesn't* point backwards to any earlier commit, because *there is no earlier commit*.  So using `HEAD^`, we ask Git to find the commit that comes before `A`, and *no commit comes before `A` and we get an error*.

---

<sup>1</sup>The default usually involves waiting at least 30 days.  We can push this ahead using some janitorial type commands.  On sites like GitHub, commits may *never* get cleaned up.

---

#### So: what *can* you do here?

There is one option for "deleting" this commit.  As before, it doesn't actually *go away*, it just gets lost until Git's janitorial functions clean it up someday (if ever).  The option we have here is to *delete the branch name*.

There are several problems with this.  The most important one is that you cannot delete the branch name that you are *using*.  You're *using* `main` or `master` *right now*, so you can't delete it.

To fix this problem, you need to create a new branch name.  But a branch name *must point to a commit*.  You only have *one commit*, and that's commit `A`.  So *all your branch names have to point to commit `A`.*

The main solution to *this* problem is simple: delete the repository completely.  With no repository, there are no commits, and no branches, and hence no commit `A`.  If you can use that solution, that's the easy one, so do that.

You might object to this solution for some reason, and in fact there's one other solution.  It's a bit tricky though:

- Consider a new, totally-empty repository, that you make by running `git init`.
- In this new repository, you are on some branch (`master` or `main`) but there *are no commits*.
- Since there are no commits, there are *no branch names either*.
- This means you're "on" a branch name that *does not exist*.

This special weird situation is necessary in a new, empty repository, so it has to exist in Git.  Git will allow you to re-create this situation even in a non-empty repository, using the `--orphan` flag to `git checkout` or `git switch`.

So, to get off the one branch that does exist in order to hold the one commit `A` that does exist, we will use this special feature:

```
git checkout --orphan newbranch
```

Your state is now this:

```
A   <-- main

    [newbranch (HEAD)]
```

You are now on a branch named `newbranch` that does not exist and therefore does not point to any commit.  This state is weird!  But it does allow you to *delete* the name `main`, using `git branch -D main` or `git branch -d --force main`.

You can now create a new "first" commit.  We'll call it `B` here since commit `A` still exists—you just can't *find* commit `A` unless you wrote down its hash ID somewhere before you deleted the branch name.

When you make your new initial (or "root") commit, Git will now *create the branch name* at this time:

```
A   [abandoned]

B   <-- newbranch (HEAD)
```

You can now go on making more new commits as usual:

```
A   [abandoned]

B--C   <-- newbranch (HEAD)
```

and so on.  Eventually—some time after 30 days or so—Git will probably finally take out the trash and drop commit `A` entirely, so that even if you *did* write down its hash ID, and go look for it, it won't exist any more.